# C# .NET Framework Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Npgsql, Version=7.0.6.0

Tags: c#, exe, npgsql, .net-4.8

When I published my C# .NET Framework application (Task Maker Application) which is using a hosted CockroachDB database, the .exe file works in the project folder but when I drag the .exe file in a different location it stops working and I get this error even though I have installed the Npgsql library in the project: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Npgsql, Version=7.0.6.0` I want to have my projects .exe file be used by other people so what could be a possible solution?

Is there a way to embed the Npgsql library within the .exe file?

I couldn't find a solution to this problem anywhere so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: When you distribute your application, you always have to distribute _all_ the files in the bin folder (with few exceptions, such as pdb files). The exe alone will not run, you also need to copy any dependent libraries.

Comment: Starting with .Net 5 there is Single-file deployment available but for .Net 4.8 you will have to deploy all dependent libraries.

Comment: I ended up finding a solution by installing a Nuget Package in my project called Costura.Fody. After installation I clicked publish and rebuilt my project and this time I got a single working executable file which is connected to the database. I think the Costura.Fody package embeds the dll's into a single exe file but yeah i havent done much reasearch into it